# Unobtrusive javascript and dynamic html

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic, unobtrusive-javascript

I'm finding a way to make unobtrusive javascript (via `data-*` attributes) in dynamic html scenarios. Let's pretend that we have an `input` element which represents a jquery-ui datepicker:

```
<input type="date" data-min-date="today" />
```

And the js which does a work:

```
(function(){
    $(function () {
        $("input[type=date]").each(function () {
            var el = $(this);
            el.datepicker(el.data());
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Now I need unobtrusive cross-browser way to convert naked inputs into a datepickers. The inputs will be added dynamically. In general I have no control on the code which adds the datepickers. In common the code will be injected as server-side prerendered html via [jquery.ajax.unobtrusive](http://nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Ajax.Unobtrusive) or [jquery-pjax](http://pjax.heroku.com/) (they both are using jQuery.html() method). But I need more generic soution which will work in all the jQuery-enabled scenarios.

I've looked at [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-MutationEvent) but they are not supported in the IE.

Complete jsfiddle-example http://jsfiddle.net/zv9Rt/1/

Comment: How are these input elements added? Through jQuery, or by DOM?

Comment: @RobW, actually it would be a jquery-pjax or jquery.ajax.unobtrusive. They all using an jquery.html method. But I want to have more generic solution.

Comment: You can use setTimeout/setInterval to check for new insertions, or wrap `.append`, `.html` etc., and check for the existence of new `input[type=date]` elements.

Comment: @RobW I thought about setTimeout/setInterval but I do not like them.

Comment: [Livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery).

Comment: @RobW awesome! Thanks. Could you please answer the question so I can accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) • [Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery#API_Documentation).

```
$("input[type=date]").livequery(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.datepicker(el.data());
});
```

Comment: Anyway. It is using the setInterval/setTimeout so I'm going to add supprot for mutation events.

Comment: @hazzik No it's not. It wraps the `.append`, `.html` etc. methods as I described in the comments on the question. `setTimeout` is probably used to make sure that the element has been rendered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
(function(){
  $(function () {
    $('body').delegate("input[type=date]", function () {
        var $el = $(this);
        $el.datepicker($el.data());
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to include a parent selector. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/H7ZUa/1/

Comment: It is not appropriate in case when i want to use some beautiful datepicker options like showOn and other. See the example http://jsfiddle.net/zv9Rt/2/